# Only display Woocommerce child product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

I am currently using the following code to fetch WooCommerce product categories:

```
<?php
    $orderby = 'name';
    $order = 'asc';
    $hide_empty = false ;
    $cat_args = array(
        'orderby'    => $orderby,
        'order'      => $order,
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    );

    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

    if( !empty($product_categories) ){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
            echo $category->name;
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

This currently displays all categories, however I wish this to only show the child categories.

For example, if you are on the Category 1 page, it should show all children within that category only.

I've looked at many examples on here but have been unable to find something that works for what I need.

Comment: Can you share some sample query result?

Comment: You don't send your current category as a parameter, also your SQL query must filter results with this parameter. If you can share your SQL query we can observe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to woocommerce/archive-product.php file

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$parent = $queried_object->term_id;
$categories = get_term_children( $parent, 'product_cat' ); 
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) : 

echo '<ul>';

foreach($categories as $category) :

$term = get_term( $category, 'product_cat' );
echo '<li>';
echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'" >';
echo $term->name;
echo '</a>';
echo '</li>';

endforeach;

echo '</ul>';

endif;
```

This will only work on your archives. And categories with children.

It will also output grand child categories.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to get only product subcategories linked list ordered by name ASC:

```
// The product category taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';

// Get the parent categories IDs
$parent_cat_ids = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'parent'     => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields'     => 'ids'
) );

// Get only "child" WP_Term Product categories
$subcategories = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'exclude'     => $parent_cat_ids,
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'asc',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

if( ! empty( $subcategories ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo '<li>
            <a href="'. get_term_link($subcategory) .'" >' . $subcategory->name.'</a>
        </li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The code is tested and works

Answer (score 0):

Add Below Code in theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter('get_child_category', 'get_child_cat', 10, 1);
function get_child_cat($term_id = 0){
    global $wpdb;
    $result = array('status' => 'fail');
    if($term_id != 0){
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( "select ".$wpdb->prefix."terms.term_id, ".$wpdb->prefix."terms.name, ".$wpdb->prefix."terms.slug, ".$wpdb->prefix."terms.term_group, ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id, ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.taxonomy, ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.description, ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.parent, ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.count from ".$wpdb->prefix."terms left join ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy on ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.term_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."terms.term_id where ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy.parent = $term_id" );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Use below code for get array output for child category.

```
$cat = apply_filters( 'get_child_category', $term_id ); // where $term_id is your parent category id.
```

NOTE: This code is only used for single level term.
change code as per your requirement.